# Can OpenLayers.Layer.OSM (the OSM tile servers) be used in production environment?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

OpenLayers has an OpenStreetMap layer built in:
OpenLayers.Layer.OSM (are the tiles they use from OpenStreetMap servers or somewhere else?)

Can it be used in a production environment in terms of:

- suitability (speed, uptime etc.)
- licensing   (ability to use it in a paid mapping system)

Comment: many users and companies do use it in production.

Comment: @Mapperz I think the question is more about licensing and terms of service than suitability.

Comment: then the question needs to be more detailed on licensing

Comment: actually i meant suitability, but terms of service is another issue. i remember reading that although osm data is free, their tiles are not. and then i saw it available on openlayers. so i wanted to know whether i can use it - i guess from both perspectives

Comment: Can you make a more substantial edit to revise your Question to something that is more focussed, please?  You currently have two question marks, and I think two unmarked questions.  The Q&A format of GIS SE works best with one question per Question.  I recommend asking the most important one first and then research/ask the others separately.

Comment: @PolyGeo i edited again. thanks for your guidance though i thought it was one question really..

Comment: I hope you do not mind me giving more advice.  The one marked question that you have left is too broad (because it could now encompass performance, licensing, etc issues).  For example, if it is licensing that you are the most worried about then ask about that specifically, and research/ask about anything else separately.  Also, I recommend not using "edit:" and "edit2:" to flag what has changed.  We can see what has changed ourselves.  It is far more important that your Question remains or is made easy to read.

Comment: @PolyGeo i do not mind. on the contrary.. i edited again and i think it is more constructive now. i left both perspectives because i think it is more a complete question this way and more usable to the community if and when it receives an answer from the experts. thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on your own needs of your production environment:  

suitability: OSM uses only donated resources that are maintained by persons in sparetime. Thus they can't grant you a 24/7 reliability or 99, 999% availability. Also all resources are shared with people contributing or using OSM online, so they can't give you a guerantee on speed, even if they offer servers close to the users.

So please check the legal aspects on your own: [Tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy), [Legal FAQ](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ)

Comment: ... but they encourage you to set up your own server with OpenStreetMap data: http://switch2osm.org/ at no extra cost.

Comment: thanks allot @Mapper, that's what i was looking for. so this is just for convenience and testing in openlayers and should not be used for production. thanks allot

Comment: @Andre Joost - thanks, i saw that site. how *no extra cost*? you need to rent a server (A big one) and create the tiles.. no ?

Comment: I thought of "extra" as additional to server and rendering time. Google will not make you such an offer...

Comment: well, it is extra compared to just using OpenLayers.Layer.OSM :-)

Comment: My original comment should have said 'may be' rather than 'is'. In that case the hold would have been for unclear what is being asked, but as it stands Mapperz reasoning seems spot on. Were the question just about terms, someone could answer citing or directing to terms of service. If suitability were phrased 'I need x, y, z, does it meet those criteria' that would work. But as just 'can it be used for production', *that* is entirely opinion based and would vary depending on use and requirements.

Comment: The "paid mapping system" bit needs to be more specific. What are you charging for? What licensing system are you trying to use. Have you read the license? What part are you unsure about? Leaving closed until that is clarified.

Comment: Yes, the [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) used by `OpenLayers.Layer.OSM` are the tiles from the official OSM servers and therefore you have to comply with the [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy). Of course you can use any other tiles as long as you comply with their terms of use, or [serve your own tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/). There is also a [list of paid tile providers](http://switch2osm.org/providers/).

Comment: @Mapperz Please unlock the topic. Then my comment might be an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) used by `OpenLayers.Layer.OSM` are the tiles from the official OSM servers and therefore you have to comply with the [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy). Of course you can use any other tiles as long as you comply with their terms of use, or [serve your own tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/). There is also a [list of paid tile providers](http://switch2osm.org/providers/).